# Is there a reference for the following generating function identities?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

For the Motzkin and Schröder numbers respectively, we have the following identities: $$ Mk(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg{(} -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{a=0}^{n+2} (-3)^{k} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{a} \binom{ \frac{1}{2}}{b} \Bigg{)}z^{n} = \frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1-2z-3z^2}}{2z^2} \quad ,$$ (where: $b = n + 2 - a $) and $$S(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_{n} z^{n} = \frac{1-x-\sqrt{1-6z+z^2}}{2z} \quad ,  $$ where $s_{n}$ is given by $$ s_{n} = s_{n-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s_{k}s_{n-1-k} \quad . $$
I obtained these identities from [these](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroederNumber.html) [pages](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MotzkinNumber.html) on mathworld. However, I can't find where the author(s) of the mathworld article found the aforementioned identities within the list of references he or she provides.

Can you please help me find a correct reference for both of these formulas?

Comment: The Reference section on the Mathworld pages listed provide the articles that can be searched for more information.

Comment: @Leucippus Yep I know, I just can't find the two formulas above in any of the articles or books mentioned in the reference section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just a few with the generating functions or expansions.

1) [Matthias Schork](http://www.math.rochester.edu/ojac/vol2/Schork_2007.pdf)
2) [Robert A. Sulanke](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL3/SULANKE/sulanke.html)
3) [Sen-Peng Eu](http://www.math.tku.edu.tw/files/archive/7_ac0fe6b1.pdf)
4) [Toufik Mansour](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Schork/schork3.pdf)
5) [Ira M. Gessel](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/slides/schroder.pdf)
6) [Eva Y. P. Deng](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07005112)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't register at the moment, so I can't upvote your answer either. Would've done that otherwise..

Comment: Nice selection. +1